# Cleaning up with die

Tags: perl

I was wondering if there is any way of doing some clean up using die. For example, if I created some files, but I would like them to be deleted if the program runs into a situation where it needs to die.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`END` blocks are executed even if the program `die`s.

```
use File::Temp qw( tempfile );

# create "things"
my ($fh, $filename) = tempfile();

# die because of a problem
die ('a problem occured');

# clean up when dying
END { unlink $filename; }
```

If you want to do something only on `die` and not on a normal exit, you can use `%SIG` - just be aware that the handler *replaces* the normal `die` behavior, which you have to invoke yourself:

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    unlink $filename;
    CORE::die @_;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So in your example, tempfile() conatins a die function?

Comment: Well, no, in my example `tempfile` (from the `File::Temp` module) creates a temporary file and returns an open filehandle and the filename, which I then set up the `END` block to delete on exit.

Comment: I made an edit, so that it is more clear from the example... (if the edit will get accepted)

Comment: File::Temp will do this for you (`tempfile(UNLINK=>1)`)

Comment: The example just wanted to demonstrate the usage of an `END`. So the usage of files are just an example (also in the question). But good point!

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for an END block (see [perlsub](https://metacpan.org/module/perlsub)).  However, there are also many other variations on that theme.  For example, [Guard](https://metacpan.org/module/Guard), which will allow cleanup from exiting a scope (whether by return, die, or goto), or just plain creating your own object with a DESTROY method, sticking your cleanup in that DESTROY method.

In this specific case, you may also be interested in [File::Remove](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Remove)::clean - though it targets test files, it may also solve this particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

Another variation on this theme is a `try`/`finally` block, such as is given by `Try::Tiny`:

```
use Try::Tiny;

my ($fh, $filename) = tempfile();
try {
    some code here...;
}
finally {
    unlink $filename;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are temporary files, that you want deleted when you are done whether you died or not, use [File::Temp](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aTemp).